# Raster vertical pixel offset (ALOS AVNIR)

Tags: imagery, satellite, envi

I am working with ALOS AVNIR-2 level 1a. There is a vertical offset/shift of each and every pixel column. It gives sort of a stripy appearance when zooming in. Does anyone have experience with this and know how to correct it, preferably in envi, arc or gdal.
It does not seem to be software dependent (opened it in ENVI version 4 and 5, ArcGIS, nest, beam)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phenomena is referred to as staggered lines or staggered-linear. It is apparently inherent to all level 1a and 1b ALOS AVNIR 2 data.
One workaround is to open the files in ERDAS 9.3, which will display the data correctly. It can then be safed as a geotif that wont have have the staggering.

An alternativ would be to open the original data as a matrix in Python/matlab/R and shift every even/uneven column by 5 pixels up/down.